# re-render current view based on language selection

Tags: react-native

New to React-Native and struggling with update the current view. I have a component LanguageSelector which is loaded by App component. Now when the language is changed, I want the App component strings to be updated to the newly selected language.

The language selector component is also loaded to the header component once the user logs in and can change the language at any time. I have seen [this explanation](https://davidwalsh.name/react-force-render) but it seems bad to call this.forceUpdate() by listening to language changes on each component and it gets worse when the components are nested.

I am using react-native-localization and all I am doing there is (and it works):

```
import LocalizedStrings from 'react-native-localization';

let strings = new LocalizedStrings({
  en: {
    hello : 'hello'
  },
  kin: {
    hello : 'mir'
  },
  fr: {
    hello: 'bonjor'
  },
});

export function setLanguage(language) {
  strings.setLanguage(language == null ? 'en' : language);
}

export function languageKey(key) {
  return strings[key];
}
```

the App Component is:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import styles from './style';
import {Text, View, ImageBackground} from 'react-native';
import LanguageSelector from '../../components/LanguageSelector';
import {languageKey} from '../../shared/localization';
export default class App extends Component {


  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <ImageBackground
        source={require('../../assets/1.jpg')}
        style={styles.backgroundImage}>
        <View style={styles.loginScreenContainer}>
        <LanguageSelector/>
         <Text>{languageKey('hello')}</Text>
        </View>
      </ImageBackground>
    );
  }
}
```

and LanguageSelector have a simple method that imports and uses setLanguage:

```
  setLanguage('fr')
```

Full code is:

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View, Picker} from 'react-native';
import {appLocales, languageKey, setLanguage, currentLanguage} from '../shared/localization';
export default class LanguageSelector extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
        language : currentLanguage()
    }
  }

  selectedLanguage(language){
      this.setState({language})
      setLanguage(language)
  }

  render() {
    const languages = appLocales();
    return (
      <View>
        <Picker
          selectedValue={this.state.language}
          style={{height: 50, width: 200, color:'#fff'}}
          onValueChange={(itemValue, itemIndex) =>
            this.selectedLanguage(itemValue)
          }>
          {languages.map((prop, key) => {
            return (
              <Picker.Item label={languageKey(prop)} value={prop} key={prop} />
            );
          })}
        </Picker>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

The language selector component does reflect the selected language's strings but not App component.

How does one handle nested components for e.g. app component

```
 <LanguageSelector/>
 <Component1/>
 <Component2/>
```

and component1 loads other component:

```
<SomeChildComponent/>
```

Comment: Your App render method has a syntax error: you probably wanted to put <Text> inside of <LanguageSelector> and </View> on the next line should probably be </LanguageSelector>.

Comment: Please include your LanguageSelector code in your question

Comment: @dols3m added the languageSelector code and removed the extra view, thanks for spotting it out.

Answer (score 1):

When language is changed in your LanguageSelector component, LanguageSelector state updates, but that state change does not involve its parent App component, so App does not re-render. `languageKey()` call simply maps key to appropriate string during a render, but without re-render it won't update. What you need instead is to have language state in your App component.

When you need a child component to update its parent's state you can pass a callback as a prop to the child (e.g. `onLanguageChange`). In your case you can create a method on your App component, bind it in the constructor, and then pass it to LanguageSelector. A method is preferred to something like `<LanguageSelector onLanguageChange={(language) => { this.setState({ language }); }} />`, because in the latter case new function will be created on every App re-render and that will trigger LanguageSelector to re-render because of changed props. This approach works well if LanguageSelector is the direct child of the App component.

If you plan to nest LanguageSelector deep in your component tree, it's easier to use React Context API to achieve the same idea. Moreover, with this approach you can wrap your Context Provider in a different component and refactor language state and language change handler method out of your App component into this new component. Something like this:

```js
const LanguageContext = React.createContext({});

class LanguageProvider extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      language: 'en',
      // Method needs to be bound to be used as callback
      setLanguage: this.setLanguage.bind(this),
    };
  }

  setLanguage(newValue) {
    this.setState({ language: newValue });
  }

  render() {
    const { children } = this.props;
    return (
      <LanguageContext.Provider value={this.state}>
        {children}
      </LanguageContext.Provider>
    );
  }
}
```